# Setting a TextBox as Autofit: Shrink Text on Overflow (Powerpoint 2003)

Tags: apache-poi

`HSLFTextBox`es don't seem to have the ability to set an `Autofit` property, even though they actually inherit the correct nested class definitions for Autofit, and [the XSLFTextBox *does* have that ability](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xslf/usermodel/XSLFTextShape.html#setTextAutofit(org.apache.poi.sl.usermodel.TextShape.TextAutofit)). Is this just an API gap that hasn't been plugged yet, or is there a different way to achieve shrink text on overflow?

This question is based on the following jars:

- poi-3.14-20160307.jar
- poi-scratchpad-3.14-20160307.jar

Comment: What version of Apache POI are you trying this with? And if it isn't the latest, what happens when you upgrade?

Comment: @Gagravarr thanks - added that into the question. As far as I know those are the latest jars.